# "See also" vs. "Also see" as a heading

Tags: word-order

I was surprised to se that there consistently is  an "Also see"-section on [this wiki (example)](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Absurd). The heading I would expect is "See also", which is used e.g. on Wikipedia ([example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reductio_ad_absurdum#See_also)). I think "See also" is clearly more common than "Also see" in this context. My question is whether "Also see" should be regarded as *incorrect*.

My interpretation of the syntax is that the heading starts a sentence of sorts, where the items that follow are proper nouns, and that "Also see" is an incorrect way to start such a sentence. For example "See also Pythagoras' theorem" is a grammatically correct full sentence, while, as far as I understand, "Also see Pythagoras' theorem" is not correct without a comma between "Also" and "see".

I have also found [a discussion](https://familypedia.fandom.com/wiki/Forum:See_Also_vs_Also_See) on another wiki, where "Also see" is argued to be incorrect on the grounds that the adverb ("also") should precede "its object" (the items that follow) as closely as possible. The thinking is that it is *what* one is seeing that changes, not the seeing itself (as if one has just been tasting or smelling). I'm not sure whether this reasoning is reliable.

Comment: It becomes grammatical when written as "Also, see ...". So think of the comma as being elided in the heading.

Comment: 'See too the ...' is fine in the UK, while 'Too, see the ...' sounds unnatural. The main rule is Orwell's Sixth, 'Avoid anything sounding outlandish', but the difficulty is that there are different dialects.

Comment: Normal grammar doesn't apply to headings. Furthermore, it makes sense to put the important word "also" before "see" which carries little meaning. Some adverbs like "too" (meaning in addition) typically go at the end of a sentence/clause/phrase but others more commonly go at the start. An adverb modifies a verb ("see") not a noun (the things listed). I notice that you don't cite any authoritative reference saying "also see" is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea—the syntax does represent the start a sentence of sorts. It starts a sentence in the imperative form, where there is an omitted but understood subject—*you*.

If you can see that, then the question, really, is why is it *see also* rather than *also see*? Wouldn’t you agree that one of these is unnatural? ([Note that no comma goes after *also*](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=117599932).)

> (1) *Eat oranges. Also eat apples.*
>
> (2) *Eat oranges. Eat also apples.*

Why is it *see also*, then? Because *see also* is an idiom in citation style:

> **see also**
>  Used to refer a reader to another work that is related to the topic being discussed.
> <sub>Watkin’s interpretation
> of this scene from Hamlet clearly supports the theory. See also the
> analysis by J. R. Prewitt on the matter.</sub>
>  <sub>See also:
> *also*, *see*</sub>
>  <sub>Source: [***Farlex Dictionary of Idioms***—see also](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/see+also)</sub>

We naturally accept it in that context. But if you don’t need that context, the choice is yours.

---

<sub>See also [Bluebook Citation 101—Academic Format > Signals](https://guides.libraries.uc.edu/c.php?g=222758&p=1473417)</sub>

<sub>or, if you prefer . . .</sub>

<sub>Also see [Bluebook Citation 101—Academic Format > Signals](https://guides.libraries.uc.edu/c.php?g=222758&p=1473417)</sub>

Comment: How is the "omitted but understood subject" relevant for the example with oranges and apples? It seems that "Also eat apples" becomes natural because it is preceded by "Eat oranges", not because of the implicit subject?

Comment: It sounded like maybe you were looking for a place to put an adverb between a subject and a verb. But of course such a place doesn’t exist in most imperative constructions. The sentence preceding *Also eat apples* is irrelevant in terms of syntax.

Comment: 'See also' is certainly a fixed expression, but idioms are the subset whose members display unusual sense of at least one of the component words and/or stretched grammar. Positioning of 'also' after a verb isn't that unusual.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth — *See also* is certainly ”a grammatically atypical use of words” — found in its own special world of citation-speak. Also, I can't think of an imperative sentence where *also* would naturally follow the verb.

Comment: Over 2.3 million (raw) Google hits for "try also to".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth — But that’s preceding a verb.

Comment: Quite right; incorrect example. But almost a quarter of a million raw Ghits for "take also the", 2 million for "try also the",  and a third of a million for "show also the".  There are imperatives amongst the examples (eg 'Question: Determine the speed of the block at B. Show also the datum and the direction of positive axis with the arrowhead in the rough ...'). The instructions come across as rather didactic, but the form is not uncommon.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth — Still unnatural. Search those under Books; *try also the* seems to have found its niche in travel guide recommendations.

Comment: I'd say 'Leave also enough time to visit the Acropolis' is common enough (though commands using 'in addition' and synonyms aren't all that common as it is). 'Carry also a few passport-size pictures' ... they do seem travel-orientated, don't they. 'Find also the number of ways they can sit round a circular table' shows a typical maths usage. 'Take also a few handfuls of very small stones' appears in a gardening article.